# vSphere 5.5 in HA Environment and Autostart VM's

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

We have the setup as above which is "managed" by our vendor. During a recent power outage we found that none of the VM's came up upon the return of power (roughly 25 VM's), which once we discovered this issue we had the vendor start them up for us.

Looking into why they aren't setup to auto-start the vendor told us that since we are running in High Availability (HA) that this was not possible.

Is this true? I know how I can setup VM's to auto-start and looking at the configuration screens it appears you can do this with our datacenter. If not directly possible using the given tools is there scripting we could do to make this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The Virtual Machine startup settings (accessed from the Configuration tab of each host) don't have any bearing on virtual machine startup in an HA cluster. The VM restart priority settings of the HA cluster control VM restarts for each VM.

You need to make sure you have your virtual machine restart priority configured for your VM's in the HA settings of the cluster.

Assuming the power outage affected all of your hosts simultaneously, and assuming that your HA VM restart priority was configured for your virtual machines (to any setting except disabled), they should have restarted after the hosts restarted. If they didn't, you need to investigate why they didn't.